# appending staging table to main, based on multiple columns, lots of nulls

Tags: sql, ms-access

Bringing rows from accounting system into staging table.  Want to append NEW recs in staging table to main table.  There is no primary key because there is no unique identifier in the row besides looking at every column.  Lots of nulls because not every column needs filled in.

Example data:

```
Staging:

    budget_line|date     |fund|amount|description|PO_number

    1          |20140623 |xyz |12.00 |donut      |{null}
    1          |{null}   |xyz |3.00  |{null}     |12345
    1          |20140623 |abc |4.00  |tire       |{null}
    2          |20140623 |xyz |12.00 |donut      |{null}
    1          |20140623 |xyz |12.00 |bobs donut |{null}
```

```
Main:

    budget_line|date     |fund|amount|description|PO_number

    1          |20140623 |xyz |12.00 |donut      |{null}
    1          |{null}   |xyz |3.00  |{null}     |12345
    1          |20140623 |abc |4.00  |tire       |{null}
```

I've been doing it like this:

`INSERT INTO Main
    SELECT budget_line
    ,date
    ,fund
    ,amount
    ,description
    ,PO_number
    FROM Staging
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT budget_line
       ,date
       ,fund
       ,amount
       ,description
       ,PO_number
       FROM Main
       WHERE ((Staging.budget_line = Main.budget_line)
               OR
             (Staging.budget_line is null AND Main.budget_line is null))
               AND
             ((Staging.date = Main.date)
               OR
             (Staging.date is null AND Main.date is null))
               AND
             ((Staging.fund = Main.fund)
               OR
             (Staging.fund is null AND Main.fund is null))
               AND
             ((Staging.amount = Main.amount)
               OR
             (Staging.amount is null AND Main.amount is null))
               AND
             ((Staging.description = Main.description)
               OR
             (Staging.description is null AND Main.description is null))
               AND
             ((Staging.PO_number = Main.PO_number)
               OR
             (Staging.PO_number is null AND Main.PO_number is null))
    )`

I'm getting some that aren't coming over and I can't figure out why.  I have about 28 fields though.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a problem with your null handling..

Try this instead - it concatenates all of the fields into a single key column, and tests that:

```
INSERT INTO Main
SELECT budget_line
,date
,fund
,amount
,description
,PO_number
FROM Staging
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM Main
   WHERE Staging.budget_line & Staging.date & Staging.fund & Staging.amount & Staging.description & Staging.PO_number =
   Main.budget_line & Main.date & Main.fund & Main.amount & Main.description & Main.PO_number)
```

Comment: I'll test this when I get a chance but it should work.  I thought of this but thought the nulls would mess up the concat so I didn't use it. Thx!